# custom color map for pcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm following the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) for creating a custom color map.  The map I want looks like this:

[image]

Here's the dictionary I came up with:

```
   cdict = {'red':   ((0.00,  0.0, 0.0),
               (0.25,  1.0, 0.0),
               (0.50,  0.0, 0.0),
               (0.75,  1.0, 0.0),
               (1.00,  1.0, 0.0)),

     'green': ((0.00,  0.0, 0.0),
               (0.25, 1.0, 1.0),
               (0.50, 1.0, 1.0),
               (0.75, 1.0, 1.0),
               (1.00,  0.0, 0.0)),

     'blue':  ((0.00,  1.0, 1.0),
               (0.25,  0.0, 0.0),
               (1.00,  0.0, 0.0))
    }
```

But it's not giving me the results I want.  For example, value 0.5 is rendered using red.

Here's what the rest of code looks like:

```
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap('bgr', cdict)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=cmap)

plt.pcolor(dist, cmap='bgr')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(dist.index), 1), dist.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.1, len(dist.columns), 1), dist.columns, rotation=40)

for y in range(dist.shape[0]):
    for x in range(dist.shape[1]):
        plt.text(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, dist.iloc[y,x],
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center', rotate=90
                 )
plt.show()
```

Here's a sample of the rendered heatmap:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that 0.5 is showing up as red in your plot is likely just because your `vmin` and `vmax` are not 0.0 and 1.0.  Most matplotlib 2D plotting routines set vmax to the maximum value in the array by default, which looks like it is 0.53 in your case.  If you want 0.5 to be green, set `vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0` in the call to `pcolor`.

Your colormap dict is nearly correct, but as you have it now there are hard transitions to yellow/green at the 0.25 and 0.75 points, you should change those lines in 'red' from

```
           (0.25,  1.0, 0.0),
           (0.50,  0.0, 0.0),
           (0.75,  1.0, 0.0),
```

to

```
           (0.25,  1.0, 1.0),
           (0.50,  0.0, 0.0),
           (0.75,  1.0, 1.0),
```

to get the colorscale you want.  This is the result:

[image: corrected colorscale]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your color dictionary is wrong. For example, the first entry for the start of the colormap is:

```
'red':   (0.00,  0.0, 0.0)
'green': (0.00,  0.0, 0.0)
'blue':  (0.00,  1.0, 1.0)
```

which gives RGB = 001 = blue. Also, I'm not sure how `LinearSegmentedColormap` is going to behave when some intervals (like index `0.5` in `blue`) are undefined.

This seems to give the correct results:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

pl.close('all')

cdict = {
  'red':   ((0.00, 1.0, 1.0),
            (0.25, 1.0, 1.0),
            (0.50, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.75, 1.0, 1.0),
            (1.00, 0.0, 0.0)),

  'green': ((0.00, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.25, 1.0, 1.0),
            (0.50, 1.0, 1.0),
            (0.75, 1.0, 1.0),
            (1.00, 0.0, 0.0)),

  'blue':  ((0.00, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.25, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.50, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.75, 0.0, 0.0),
            (1.00, 1.0, 1.0))
}

cm_rgb = LinearSegmentedColormap('bgr', cdict)

pl.figure()
pl.imshow(np.random.random((20,20)), interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm_rgb)
pl.colorbar()
```

See [the matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap) for documentation of `LinearSegmentedColormap`.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see I got the color map image wrong.   No, the dict is right, it's just the image has to be a mirror reflection of what ti was.  I just fixed that.  The problem is that values of .5 get mapped to red rather than green.  And the docs link you provided makes it clear that r,g,b entries don't need to align.  In the very example there one of the color components more intervals defined than others.